# missing private key for certificates

Tags: ios, certificate

I am trying to upload an application, but its giving me this message [image]

[image]
[image]
I open the Keychain , and exported the certificate with its private key as p.12, and then click it, but nothing changed. Knowing that there are 4 certificates for this account, three of them became revoked suddenly, while one of them is still valid.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a distribution certificate in your keychain that has a private-key attached? Because it is possible to have just the certificate without a key in it.

Comment: check the new screenshot added, yes keychane has private key attached

Comment: Those are all "just" Development-certificates. To distribute an app you will need a "Distribution"-certificate, which is why you get the error in the first screenshot.

Comment: yes it contains a development certificate, since i released it from about 3 days to the app store, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your keychain, there are multiple keys named 'Michel Ghosn'. Those multiple entries for the same name can be conflicting. Try by removing those and install it again.

Comment: ill try it and come back to you